# VirtualBox raw drive using UUID instead of device name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I want to attach an actual drive to a VirtualBox VM, so I [followed the instructions here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk), which says to do this:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdX
```

That creates a virtual hard drive (`file.vmdk`) which can be attached to the VM, and it is a sort of wrapper for the actual drive. And that works.

However based on which drives I have connected at any one time, the `sdX` device name changes, and the wrong physical drive is then shown to the VM.

So I want to specify the UUID name instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lsblk` command like this:

```
sudo lsblk /dev/sdaX -no UUID
```

To get the partition uuid but you can also use the device file system.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

To confirm which UUID you want to use. That file will refer to which ever /dev/sdX matches the UUID.

Then use that in the xboxmanage command.

Comment: I know how to get the UUID, but how do I use it? That is not a documented option.

Comment: @lonix Just like any other device file.

Comment: What do you mean? `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk UUID` doesn't work?

Comment: @lonix Enter the `ls` command that will list device files by UUID but they are files that can be input into VBoxManage.

Comment: Okay I understand now - though I used `by-id` instead of `by-uuid` to get the whole disk though. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, partitions have a UUID, but not the whole drive. It should have a unique ID, though. You can easily create a vmdk by pointing the command to the latter:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename <image_name>.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk/by-id/<ID_of_the_drive>
```

Or open an existing vmdk file with a text editor and replace `/dev/sdX` by hand.